# Declaring a global CHAR array from shell in C

Tags: c, arrays, shell, concurrency, global-variables

I have a problem with global variables in C. I have to create an array of strings with C. The number of strings will be determined by the argument passed by the shell (`number_of_string = atoi(argv[1])`). So I think the best way to do this is with an array of `number_of_strings` pointers. Every elemnt of this array will point to a section of memory dinamically reserved with malloc. The main problem is that I need to define the size of the array before the execution of main (argv[1] doesn't exist yet), as a global variable. I don't know how I could solve this. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Why do you need to define the size of the array prior to execution? From a logical standpoint, how do expect that to happen if you only know the number of strings at runtime? Define the pointer and use `malloc` to allocate the string pointers.

Comment: `char **strings`.  `strings = malloc(sizeof(char*)*atoi(argv[1]));`  Each `string[x]` is then the result of `malloc(sizeof(char)*<the_length_of_the_string_to_store>);`.  If, for whatever reason, you want it to be global, just make `char **strings` defined globally.  You then initialize it as stated previously in `main()` or wherever is appropriate.

Comment: It's an exercise of concurrency. I have to create a circular buffer where I'll store a number of strings determined by the user (passing the number by the shell). This is the part missing to finish the program.

Comment: If it's a circular buffer, that's a whole other matter. This means, if the number of strings exceeds the maximum imposed by the buffer, the first string that's been added will be overwritten by the most recent one.

Comment: Yes, but that's not the problem. Everything that has to do with the circular buffer is already solved with the use of semaphores.

Comment: What problem do semaphores solve for you specifically? They resolve race conditions, which might be important for a data structure such as a circular buffer, but have you really implemented a circular buffer yet? If not, I don't see the problem. A circular buffer consists of a fixed-size buffer anyway. Just surround it with some abstraction (functions for adding/removing elements and whatever you want) and store the strings there.

Comment: @eddiem I don't understand the syntax of your solution. What's strings.strings? I've only seen points after variables when using structures.

Comment: @HastatusXXI It's not `strings.strings`.  I was just showing the variable declaration followed by the initialization.  It's a two-dimensional array.  I didn't post a full answer with appropriate formatting since the full problem isn't clear yet.  You first allocate the number of strings you want, then you allocate each individual string within the array as needed.  How is the size of each individual string determined?

Comment: @Downvoter I use semaphores to control the flow of the data in the circular buffer. The circular buffer is already implemented. The only problem is I don't know the size it will have until main is executed (it's supposed to be atoi(argv[1])). The circular buffer has to be global because it's used by several process. The last option would be create the buffer in main and passing it to every process in pthread_create, but I think that's not how things should be done.

Comment: @eddiem The size of the string will be 66 - 100 characters length. I generate the strings, so I'd have to reserve 100*sizeof(char) space in memory.

Comment: As a clarification: The size of the buffer will be at most half of the number of strings. But, I repeat, I don't have the problem with the management of the circular buffer specifically. It's with its creation. Its size will be determined by atoi(argv[1]) and it has to be global.

Comment: Why do you want to determine the size of the circular buffer at runtime? It's the very nature of a circular buffer that its buffer has a fixed size and newly added elements that don't fit into the buffer anymore cause the buffer to "circulate," to start from the beginning of the buffer, *overwriting* its elements. If you have a problem with that overwriting and therefore want to extend the size of your circular buffer, choose another data structure because that just defeats the purpose of a circular buffer. It is *meant* to be overwritable.

Comment: I wonder if it's meant to be circular in the sense that there are a fixed number of strings, so that when you hit the max, it overwrites string 0, but string 1 remains intact, even if string 0 happens to be longer than the old string 0.

Comment: The data are overwritten, indeed. It's just an academic exercise. Of course I wouldn't ask the user the size of the buffer in a real program. The size is fixed once the buffer is created, then it works as a common circular buffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this address your problem?

```
#include <stdlib.h>

char **strings;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int size;
    int i;
    if ( argc < 2 )
        return 1;

    size = atoi(argv[1]);

    if ( size <= 0 )
        return 2;

    strings = malloc(sizeof(char*)*size);

    for ( i = 0 ; i < size ; i++ ) {
        strings[i] = malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
    }

    // You now have argv[1] 100-byte strings (don't forget about NULL terminators)
}
```

Comment: Don't forget free them all.